# Grid field type with 'row_id' variables is not working properly in channel tag

Tags: channel-entries, channel, grid

I am using grid type field for express engine channel and i want to show result based to row_id and it was working when i have entered row_ids but it is not working when row_id  are not there.

for eg. I have created a channel named as 'XYZ'  and having following channel fields there :

```
1) user_type : text 

2) profile : grid

       a) first_name : text 

       b) last_name :  text

       c) user_name : text 

       d) age : text
```

Now i want to show user listing for a entry and  i am getting row_id for grid from custom query in code. 
i have used following code :

```
.............

//here we are getting row_ids from custom query as

// if condition here
<?php  $rowsId="10|11|12"; ?>

// else condition  (set $rowsId value as -1  in case when we are not getting row_id from custom query)

<?php $rowsId = "-1" ; ?> 

..............

{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz" entry_id=1}
    {profile row_id="<?php echo $rowsId; ?>"}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
    {/profile}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the code

```
{profile row_id="<?php echo $rowsId; ?>"}
```

it is working in case of   `<?php  $rowsId="10|11|12"; ?>`

but it is not working in case of  `<?php $rowsId = "-1"; ?>`

It should not give us  result set in that case (should be empty) but It shows one row in result set and i have also tried '$rowsId' value as 0 instead of -1 but it is also not working.

Please help me what is missing/wrong here or give me a solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is bug in EE grid field. If you are passing invalid parameter for row_id="ABC@#4" it will still show first row from grid.
You can check $rowsId variable and set condition accordingly.

```
<?php
If ($rowsId == '-1') {
    echo "No result to show";
} else{ ?>
    {profile row_id="<?php echo $rowsId; ?>"}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
   {/profile}
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php in this way, you could just not show the output if it is set to -1

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz" entry_id=1}
  <?php if ($rowsId != -1) {?>
    {profile row_id="<?php echo $rowsId; ?>"}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
    {/profile}
   <?php } ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```